# C# - Como fazer um simples Web Scraping

Tags: c#, scraping

Quero realizar a leitura de informações de uma pagina HTML de uma [rádio online](http://hts01.painelstream.net:9074/index.html?sid=1). Já tentei realizar a leitura utilizando HtmlAgilityPack, contudo sem sucesso pois a pagina em questão que estou trabalhando não utiliza ElementId, imagino que o mesmo não é um problema, contudo não sei utilizar a API e os exemplos que encontrei necessitavam utilizar o método *GetElementbyId()*.

Estou precisando receber duas informações desta pagina(Playing Now, Playing Next), e atribuí-las a suas respectivas variável. De preferencia utilizando funções nativas do C#, contudo não tenho problema em utilizar alguma API como o *HtmlAgilityPack*(Principalmente se assim o procedimento for simplificado).

Aqui está um print da página que desejo realizar o Web Scraping.
[image: Print da pagina para extrair as informações]

O código que tenho atualmente está assim:

```
namespace Web_Scraping{
class SimplesWebScraping{
    void Main()
    {
        //Realiza o download da página em String
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        string pagina = webClient.DownloadString("http://hts01.painelstream.net:9074/index.html?sid=1");

        //Declara variáveis do tipo string para armazenar os dados/conteúdos extraidos no website.
        string playingNow = string.Empty;
        string playingNext = string.Empty;

        //Realiza o Web_Scraping
        //Como fazer isso?

        //Escreve os dados extraídos
        Console.Write("Reproduzindo Agora: " + playingNow);
        Console.Write("Reprodução Seguinte: " + playingNext);
    }
}
}
```

Qual é a melhor maneira de realizar este procedimento, alguém pode me mostrar exemplo de códigos para está ação? Já lhes digo Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: A pergunta foi melhor respondia em outro tópico. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/302606/como-coletar-dados-de-uma-pagina-web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Expressoes Regulares](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular)

Esse ainda é o melhor jeito que lidar com string como vc está procurando.

Com RegEx - Regular Expressions - vc criar um *pattern* e conflita esse contra um texto. E todos os *matches* que existirem, serão retornados.

#### Exemplo:

Pattern `([A-Z])\w+`: Sequencia que inicie com caracteres de `A` a `Z` - maiúsculas - e depois sejam seguidas de letras `/w` em pelo menos uma ocorrência `+`.

Se executar esse *pattern* contra o texto abaixo:

> **Bem** vindo ao **Stack** **Overflow**!

O retorno será: `[ "Bem", "Stack", "Overflow" ]`, pois são as sequências que se iniciam com letras maiúsculas, são seguidos de mais letras - e apenas letras.

Esse é o RegExr Tester que eu recomendo: https://regexr.com/
Muito bom para testar e para aprender RegExpr.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @Thiago Lunardi.

Comment: Por nada. Nao esqueça de marcar a resposta como ideal. :)