# Como coletar dados de uma pagina web?

Tags: c#, regex, web-scraping, replace, webclient

A coleta de dados web, ou Web Scraping, é uma forma de mineração que permite a extração de dados de sites da web convertendo-os em informação estruturada para posterior análise. Exponham aqui suas ideias e alternativas mais eficiente para a realização dessa tarefa.

Answer (score 10):

A melhor forma de se obter dados de um documento é fazendo uso da Classe `Regex`. Usando expressões regulares imutáveis para obter os dados desejados podemos realizar consultas em documentos ou até mesmo em uma página-web.

Para demonstração criaremos um programa que obtém a quantidade de votos que sua pergunta recebeu no stackoverflow.

[image: Print - Votos]

Antes de tudo vamos encontrar no código fonte de nossa página web onde está a quantidade de votos e em seguida criaremos a expressão regular para encontrá-la em qualquer pergunta presente no stackoverflow.

**REALIZANDO WEB SCRAPING MANUALMENTE**

No navegador Google Chrome clique com o botão direito do mouse no lugar onde deseja obter as informações. Clique em Inspecionar para abrir o Inspecionador de Elementos do navegador.

[image: Como abrir o Inspecionador de Elementos]

No inspecionador de elementos clique com o botão direito do mouse e copie o a string do texto desejado.

[image: Copie o a string do trecho de texto desejado]

Como resultado obteremos a seguinte string: `<span itemprop="upvoteCount" class="vote-count-post ">0</span>`

Podemos atestar que o número correspondente a quantidade de votos na pergunta atualmente é zero (0) e está entre duas Strings.
Primeira String: `<span itemprop="upvoteCount" class="vote-count-post ">` 
Segunda String: `</span>`

**CRIANDO A EXPRESSÃO REGULAR**

Com essas informações em mãos agora já podemos desenvolver nossa expressão regular. Para facilitar o nosso trabalho utilizaremos um site para testar nossa expressão em funcionamento.

Abra o site [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester) e cole a nossa string em `Input`. Em `Pattern` da mesma maneira, substituiremos apenas o número zero pela expressão regular `\d+` conforme é possível observar na imagem.

[image: Regexstorm.net]

**EXPLICANDO AS EXPRESSÃO REGULARES**

Expressões regulares são como o próprio nome sugere expressões que sinalizam determinados padrões que se repetem em um texto. Nesse caso usamos a expressão `\d` que corresponde a qualquer dígito decimal juntamente com um quantificador `+` sinalizando que ele deve pesquisar o elemento decimal anteriormente descrito, uma ou mais vezes. Assim se esse valor viesse a ser incrementado ou decrementado ele não deixaria de ser encontrado.

Para analisarmos o seu funcionamento simularemos o incremento desses dados em `Input` e o que podemos atestar no rodapé da pagina na aba `Table` é que o `Regex` foi capaz de fato de encontrar os diferentes valores na string com sucesso.

[image: Exemplo de Regex]

Para ler uma lista das expressões regulares disponíveis e obter exemplos de uso das mesmas veja as [referencias do Regex](http://regexstorm.net/reference).

**DESENVOLVENDO NOSSO WEB SCRAPING**

Crie um projeto `Console Application` com o nome `Simple Web Scraping`. Com o  intuito de organizar o nosso trabalho criaremos uma pasta em nosso projeto chamada Tools e dentro dela criaremos duas classes: `DownloadWebPage.cs` e `RegexTools.cs`.

[image: Print do Gerenciador de Soluções]

**REALIZANDO O DOWNLOAD DE UMA PÁGINA-WEB**

A classe `DownloadWebPage` será responsável por fazer o download de uma página web e retornar o resultado em uma String. Usaremos a classe `WebClient` para baixar a pagina web.

```
class DownloadWebPageString
{
    static public String Run(String _url)
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            return webClient.DownloadString(_url);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "Não foi possivel baixar a pagina web.";
        }
    }

}
```

**OBTENDO DADOS DE UMA STRING USANDO REGEX**

A classe `RegexTools` será responsável por coletar dados de uma String correspondente a página-web que obteremos posteriormente. Não apenas isso, mas também implementaremos um sistema de substituição de dados para recebermos apenas a informação que de fato desejamos.

Faremos isso através da função `Replace` disponível para manipulação de Strings em `C#`. A mesma é capaz de substituir um determinado trecho de texto por outra coisa que em nosso caso será simplesmente uma string vazia para a remoção das partes do texto não relevantes.

```
class RegexTools
{
    String text;

    public void NewDocument(String _text)
    {
        text = _text;
    }

    public String Run(String _regularExpression)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(_regularExpression);
        var match = regex.Match(text);
        String resultRegex = match.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(resultRegex);
        return resultRegex;
    }

    public String Run(String _regularExpression, String _replaceClearFirst)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(_regularExpression);
        var match = regex.Match(text);
        String resultRegex = match.ToString();
        String resultReplaceFirst = resultRegex.Replace(_replaceClearFirst, "");

        return resultReplaceFirst;
    }

    public String Run(String _regularExpression, String _replaceClearFirst, String _replaceClearSecond)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(_regularExpression);
        var match = regex.Match(text);
        String resultRegex = match.ToString();
        String resultReplaceFirst = resultRegex.Replace(_replaceClearFirst, "");
        String resultReplaceSecond = resultReplaceFirst.Replace(_replaceClearSecond, "");

        return resultReplaceSecond;
    }
}
```

**EXECUTANDO O PROGRAMA**

Na classe `Program` gerada automaticamente quando criamos nosso projeto adicionaremos ao método `Main` presente na mesma, o seguinte código comentado explicando o funcionamento do programa.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("WEB SCRAPING – COMO FAZER COLETA DE DADOS WEB?");
        // DEFINIÇÕES DE PESQUISA NO DOCUMENTO
        String paginaWeb = DownloadWebPageString.Run("https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/302606/");
        String regularExpression = "<span itemprop=\"upvoteCount\" class=\"vote-count-post \">\\d+</span>"; // ENCONTRA NA STRING NÚMEROS DECIMAIS USANDO A EXPRESSÃO REGULAR: \d+ 
        String replaceClearFirst = "<span itemprop=\"upvoteCount\" class=\"vote-count-post \">"; // DEFINE O INÍCIO DO TEXTO PARA APAGAR
        String replaceClearSecond = "</span>"; // DEFINE O FINAL DO TEXTO PARA APAGAR

        // OBTENDO OS DADOS
        RegexTools regexTools = new RegexTools();
        regexTools.NewDocument(paginaWeb); // CARREGANDO O REGEXTOOLS COM O DOCUMENTO            
        String countVotes = regexTools.Run(regularExpression, replaceClearFirst, replaceClearSecond); // OBTEMOS A QUANTIDADE DE VOTOS.
        Console.WriteLine("Quantidade de votos: " + countVotes);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Agora para compilar o projeto na IDE Visual Studio 2017 clique em `▶ Iniciar`.
[image: Compilar no Visual Studio 2017]

Após compilarmos obteremos o resultado da imagem a seguir na tela do Console da Aplicação.

[image: Resultado]

O projeto está disponível para download em meu GitHub: [Simple-Web-Scraping](https://github.com/guilhermelim/Simple-Web-Scraping)

Comment: Resposta Top!!!

Comment: Faça bom uso e quê lhe seja de alguma forma útil algum dia. Estou apenas começando no stackoverflow, espero criar mais conteúdos relevantes em breve. Obrigado @W.Faustino. 